# Mega Menus using using Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create an option at work to use mega menus, basically the designer should be able to set the level per columns for the mega menus so if there are 10 items under one category and the designer sets the level to 2 then the megamenu for that category should split into two columns of 5 items. What would be the best way to implement this using Asp.net C# and JQuery so it looks nice?.

Also, how can i do it so that if there are 10 items I can break it into columns of 5?

Relevant information:
- The data for the menu is comming from a table.
- The menu will be horizontal

I am not asking for the code but for the best approach and also the best way to go about this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can certainly handle all the interactions.

If you're asking the best way to split out the links, I think the answer is do it whichever way is easier for your team. The client-side processing to split the list won't be that much, though it's nice to do it client side if you can.

Comment: How can JQuery communicate with C#?, if i am data binding it to the menu?

Comment: it can't. jQuery is JS which is all client side. What kind of data bindings do you need? I'd suggest that your .net code spit out HTML. Use jQuery to create all the interactions/pretty it up/move things around.